# How to pass reference inside of valid() of Joi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, joi

So, I use Joi for validation and I have something like this to validate one of my enum choices(`["cookie", "pie", "lemon", "chiken"]`, and it's working.

```
// ...some code
Joi.object({
  // ...some code
  someField: Joi.string().valid("cookie", "pie", "lemon", "chiken").required(),
  // ...some code
```

But I want to use a reference like so:

```
let a = 'cookie, pie, lemon, chiken'
// ...some code
Joi.object({
  // ...some code
  someField: Joi.string().valid(a).required(),
  // ...some code
```

And it doesn't work properly... it treat it differently:

`"myfieldname" must be [cookie, pie, lemon, chiken]`

and it should be like so

`"myfieldname" must be one of [cookie, pie, lemon, chiken]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ES6 spread syntax:

```js
let a = ['cookie', 'pie', 'lemon', 'chiken'];
// ...some code
Joi.object({
  // ...some code
  someField: Joi.string().valid(...a).required(),
  // ...some code
```

EDIT: Using the old JS syntax it would look like this:

```js
let a = ['cookie', 'pie', 'lemon', 'chiken'];
// ...some code
Joi.object({
  // ...some code
  someField: Joi.string().valid.apply(null, a).required(),
  // ...some code
```

Or if you really want to give the arguments as one string instead of an array of strings:

```js
let aAsString = 'cookie, pie, lemon, chiken';
let a = aAsString.split(",").map( s => s.trim() );
```